# SSH client in C

Tags: c, ssh

How can I perform a SSH action in C program?
Like, how can I connect to a server with SSH and automatically create a list directories and print the output on screen without having SSH connection on the screen?

For example in **Python** its like this:

```
from pwn import *
s = ssh(host='SERVER_ADDRESS', user='USERNAME', password='PASSWORD')
py = s.run('cd /home/; ls)
print py.recv()
```

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to add
`from pwn import *`
at the top of the python code

Comment: Search on "c ssh library" then pick one to link to your project.  C (and C++) don't  include a bunch of task-specific libraries, you need to add your own.  If you look, libraries do exist for almost everything,

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have python code that does this - one option is to use that code and embed it into your C program, as described in the following manual: https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html. At the very least it will be a good starting point to develop what you need, though I don't see any reason this shouldn't be a viable solution in and of itself.

Comment: If someone ever wants an example of Python embedding - here is one I actually used (forgot I had it at hand when writing this answer) for parsing CSV files, though any other function should be similar to implement assuming the proper python runtime environment - https://gist.github.com/VehpuS/76e5d6edb3acbd3976daac53c0340dcc